# Mathematica lists in a weird format

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hi I have the following simple program:

```
joint = Table[0, {i, Length[labelnames]}, {j, 16}]; 

For[time = 1, 
 time < Length[topics], time++
  Do[
   joint[[l, t]]++, {l, labelsForTime[time]}, {t, topics[[time]]}
   ]
 ]
```

Result of which, joint is:
{{0, 1267, 90, 0, 0, 58, 1358, 2, 25, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2585, 
  0}, (7507 + List)[111, 773, 3302, 8092, 405, 1776, 4203, 153, 9551, 
  118, 9, 2260, 17, 665, 5586, 0], (3288 + List)[0, 43, 46, 716, 0, 
  120, 20, 2, 576, 0, 0, 246, 0, 0, 118, 0], (382 + List)[7, 80, 191, 
  87, 1, 38, 2887, 3, 1967, 0, 5, 72
....

Notice the (7505 + List), (3288 + List) .. and other similar elements in the output. I just can't figure out what these are, and how they got into `joint`, which is a simple list of lists.

Comment: probably need double brackets on  labelsForTime[[time]] i guess , hard to say witout  seeing how things are defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you missing a comma after `time++`? (I can't run your code because there are too many unknown variables...)